# Merging a list of Polygons to Multipolygons

Tags: python, geospatial, shapely

I have a list of shapely polygons

```
myList = [[<shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x110e09d90>], [<shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x110e09f90>], [<shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x110ec9150>]]
```

How would I create a `MultiPolygon` out of them? I cannot get my head around it

Comment: Your list contains several single-element lists containing one polygon each.  Your question suggests that you expect a list of polygons instead.

Comment: @Pythonista cascaded_union creates a Polygon from a Polygon list (like I posted here?)

Comment: Here's an example of `cascaded_union` usage. Easier to just look at the code and see if it's what you need http://deparkes.co.uk/2015/02/28/how-to-merge-polygons-in-python/

Comment: @Pythonista awesome, thanks! Working for the first time with shapely, pretty hard to keep track of what there is!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like you have a list of lists (each with one item). Before you do anything, make a flat list of geometries:

```
myGeomList = [x[0] for x in myList]
```

There are actually a few options to combine them. The best is to do a unary union on a list of geometries, which may result in different geometry types, such as MultiPolygon, but it not always.

```
from shapely.ops import unary_union
cu = unary_union(myGeomList)
```

Or you could pass the list to `MultiPolgyon()` or `GeometryCollection()`, but these might present issues (invalid, inability to use overlay ops, etc.)

Comment: Great Answer! Taking directly MultiPolgyon() does not throw errors but results in faulty results. Tested when combining polygons and multipolygons  to new multipolygons.

Comment: If you have a big data set, perhaps a few gigabytes, this can be really inefficient as `unary_union` will try to merge polygons which share edges – for example, if your polygons represent European countries, it will merge mainland Europe into a single polygon.  Identifying shared paths is computationally expensive, and if you don't need this and have a big data set, there must be a better solution.  I'm not quite sure what that might be, though.